# Recursive function sum of digits R

Tags: r, recursion

I try to write a recursive function that returns the sum of digits. However, the program below doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
getSum = function(i) {
    if (i < 0) {Print("Please enter a positive number")}
    if (i >= 0) {getSum(i - floor(i / 10) - i %% 10) + floor(i / 10) + i %% 10}
```

It gives two errors:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / 
options(expressions=)?
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Basic debugging techniques: think through simple cases. Let's say you call `getSum(1)`, what happens? What about `getSum(0)`? I'd recommend just working it out, but you could also add some `print` statements inside your function to help you check your work.

Comment: Also,thespacebarcanhelpthereadabilityofcode.

Comment: I think I got it: It will continue to recurse when getSum(0), which will eventually happen. Then it still won't work however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, it is recommended to use **`Recall`** for creating a recursive function.

I am using @d.b's function, but demonstrating with `Recall`

```
getSum = function( i ) 
{
  if (nchar(i) == 1){
    return(i)
  } else if (i < 0 ) {
    "Please enter a positive number"
  }else {
    print(i)
    Recall( i = floor(i/10)) +i%%10 
  }
}

getSum(0)
# [1] 0
getSum(1)
# [1] 1
getSum(-1)
# [1] "Please enter a positive number"
getSum(5)
# [1] 5
getSum(100)
# [1] 100
# [1] 10
# [1] 1
getSum( 23)
# [1] 23
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
if (i >= 0)
{sum(sapply(strsplit(as.character(i),""),as.numeric))}
```

Of course this works for whole numbers. If your need is greater more regex can be added to accommodate that

Edited! Oops totally missed that you want a recursive function

Comment: Yes! But this looks very nice as well. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Also I still do not have enough points to comment on d.b's excellent answer but it needs an edit. The i%%10 should be outside the recursion.  getSum(floor(i/10))+i%%10

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
getSum = function(i){
    i = abs(floor(i))
    if (nchar(i) == 1){
        return(i)
    } else {
        getSum(floor(i/10)) +i%%10 #Minorpt (suggested by @DashingQuark)
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer d.b. A quick edit. The i%%10 should be outside the recursion.    getSum(floor(i/10))+i%%10